# Not able to Deactivate Chatter Free user in Production

Tags: chatter, user-management, userlicense, deactivate

I am unable to deactivate Chatter free users in Production. I received the following error
"Salesforce CRM Content User is not allowed for this License Type."

Salesforce CRM Content User check box is unchecked for that user. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Try "freezing" them first, then look for any content or records they may "own" that they've uploaded. Once you've changed ownership or deleted that content, you should be able to deactivate them.